# Excel Create Collapsible Indented Row Hierarchies

Tags: excel, rows, folding

I would like to create indented collapsible row hierarchies in Excel for my spreadsheet.

I have used group function but that becomes hard to manage for me.

Here is an example of what I am trying to create:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBJY83PTiXs

Answer (score 27):

A much easier way is to go to Data and select Group or Subtotal. Instant collapsible rows without messing with pivot tables or VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Pivot Table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010177384.aspx). It has these features and many more.

If you are dead-set on doing this yourself then you could add shapes to the worksheet and use VBA to hide and unhide rows and columns on clicking the shapes.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I know how to use VBA code to hide rows, so I should use a shape button to create the effect.

Comment: Do you know if that effect is created in a pivot table - the hierarchy structure?  ~ shana

Comment: @user2533460 Yes. There are different Report Layouts to choose between, the report automatically appears with little +/- signs, you can Group, Filter, items, etc.. The Pivot Table is based on a regular table though, with column headings.

Comment: Andy, do you know how I could use an image to hide and un hide rows?

Comment: `Columns(3).Hidden = True`, `Columns("D:E").Hidden = False`. You then assign a macro containing such code, by right-clicking the image. You need to learn how to use the **Macro Recorder** in Excel to generate initial code. Good luck.